# Extend React-FC Generic Typescript-Component (Ant-Design Select)

Tags: reactjs, types, antd

I am trying to extend a Select component of ant-design.
It is possible to use the component like this:

```js
<Select<number>>
  ...
</Select>
```

Now I want to create a custom wrapper component, but the generic nesting is really hard for me to understand.

```
const BMSelect: React.FC<SelectProps<???>> = ({children, ...props}) => {
    return <Select<???> {...props}>
        {children}
    </Select>
}
```

How can I extend this select with typescript?

Ant-design provides the following interfaces/props:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Option, OptGroup, SelectProps as RcSelectProps } from 'rc-select';
import { OptionProps } from 'rc-select/lib/Option';
import { SizeType } from '../config-provider/SizeContext';
declare type RawValue = string | number;
export { OptionProps };
export declare type OptionType = typeof Option;
export interface LabeledValue {
    key?: string;
    value: RawValue;
    label: React.ReactNode;
}
export declare type SelectValue = RawValue | RawValue[] | LabeledValue | LabeledValue[];
export interface InternalSelectProps<VT> extends Omit<RcSelectProps<VT>, 'mode'> {
    suffixIcon?: React.ReactNode;
    size?: SizeType;
    mode?: 'multiple' | 'tags' | 'SECRET_COMBOBOX_MODE_DO_NOT_USE';
    bordered?: boolean;
}
export interface SelectProps<VT> extends Omit<InternalSelectProps<VT>, 'inputIcon' | 'mode' | 'getInputElement' | 'backfill'> {
    mode?: 'multiple' | 'tags';
}
export interface RefSelectProps {
    focus: () => void;
    blur: () => void;
}
declare const SelectRef: <VT extends SelectValue = SelectValue>(props: SelectProps<VT> & {
    ref?: ((instance: RefSelectProps | null) => void) | React.RefObject<RefSelectProps> | null | undefined;
}) => React.ReactElement;
declare type InternalSelectType = typeof SelectRef;
interface SelectInterface extends InternalSelectType {
    SECRET_COMBOBOX_MODE_DO_NOT_USE: string;
    Option: typeof Option;
    OptGroup: typeof OptGroup;
}
declare const Select: SelectInterface;
export default Select;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component also needs to take a generic parameter that it can pass on to the component it extends.

I don't know of a way to refer to the generic parameter inside the function, from outside of the function, but you can certainly use a function definition and type the props explicitly, rather than using `React.FC`.

```
function BMSelect<T>({ children, ...props }: SelectProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Select<T> {...props}>
      {children}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

If you look at [the source](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/ca65a985a947b2286963f9f31f3313230d433fed/components/select/index.tsx#L45) for the ant-design select component, you'll see that the generic parameter it takes extends `SelectValue`.

```
const InternalSelect = <VT extends SelectValue = SelectValue>(
```

You'll need to apply the same constraint to your `T` to extend their component correctly.

```
function BMSelect<T extends SelectValue>({ children, ...props }: SelectProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Select<T> {...props}>
      {children}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is working as expected. However, I want to add the arrow-function based approach here:

```js
const BMSelect = <T extends SelectValue = SelectValue>({ children, ...props }: SelectProps<T>) => {
    return (
        <Select<T> {...props}>
            {children}
        </Select>
    );
}
```